# There was an error in registering a user in site Charger_Community. The error message is: portal account owner must have a role

Tags: apex, community, customer-community, partner-communities, lightning-community

I am registering an account in renault community, but i am getting the following error message, even though the portal account owner has a role assigned.

> There was an error in registering a user in site Renault_Community.
>   The error message is: portal account owner must have a role.

**Workaround:**
All the existing asked questions was mentioning to assign to a role in test class. But the problem is with the line in this class,i hope so

> String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);

Please suggest a solution to avoid this error.

```
global without sharing class LightningSelfRegisterController {

    public LightningSelfRegisterController() {

    }

    private static boolean isValidPassword(String password, String confirmPassword) {
        return password == confirmPassword;
    }

    private static boolean siteAsContainerEnabled(Id networkId) {
        Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = new Auth.AuthConfiguration(networkId,'');
        return authConfig.isCommunityUsingSiteAsContainer();
    }

    private static void validatePassword(User u, String password, String confirmPassword) {
        Site.validatePassword(u, password, confirmPassword);
        return;
    }     

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String selfRegister(String firstname ,String lastname, String email, 
                                      String password, String confirmPassword, String accountId, 
                                      String regConfirmUrl, String extraFields, String startUrl, 
                                      Boolean includePassword) {

          Account existedAccount;
          System.debug('selfRegister');
          Savepoint sp = null;
          try {
              sp = Database.setSavepoint();

              System.debug('firstname' +firstname);
              System.debug('lastname' +lastname);
              System.debug('email' +email);
              System.debug('accountId' +accountId);
              System.debug('regConfirmUr' +regConfirmUrl);
              if (firstname == null || String.isEmpty(firstname)) {
                  return Label.Registration_First_name_cannot_be_empty;
              }

              if (lastname == null || String.isEmpty(lastname)) {
                  return Label.Registration_Last_name_cannot_be_empty;
              }

              if (email == null || String.isEmpty(email)) {
                  return Label.Registration_Username_cannot_be_empty;
              }       

              User u = new User();
              u.Username = email.trim();
              u.put('Email',email.trim());

              u.FirstName = firstname.trim();
              u.LastName = lastname.trim();

              String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();

              // If using site to host the community the user should not hit s1 after logging in from mobile.
              if(networkId != null && siteAsContainerEnabled(networkId)) {
                  u.put('UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI',true);
              }

              String nickname = ((firstname != null && firstname.length() > 0) ? firstname.substring(0,1) : '' ) + lastname.substring(0,1);
              nickname += String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()).substring(1,7);
              u.put('CommunityNickname', nickname);

              if (extraFields != null) {
                  List<Object> extraFieldsList = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(extraFields);        
                  for (Object thisFieldObject : extraFieldsList) {
                      Map<String,Object> thisField = (Map<String,Object>) thisFieldObject;
                      Schema.SObjectField sof = Schema.SObjectType.User.fields.getMap().get((String) thisField.get('fieldPath'));
                      u.put(sof, thisField.get('value'));
                  }
              }

              // Checks for Duplicate Community Nickname already used
              List < User > userList = [Select Id from User Where CommunityNickname = : u.CommunityNickname Limit 1];
              if (userList.size() > 0) {
                  return Label.Nickname_in_Use;
              }

              // Checks for Duplicate Email address already used
              userList = [Select Id from User Where Username = : email Limit 1];
              if (userList.size() > 0) {
                  return Label.Duplicate_Email_Message;
              }

              if (includePassword) {    
                  if (!isValidPassword(password, confirmPassword)) {
                      return Label.site.passwords_dont_match;
                  }
                  validatePassword(u, password, confirmPassword);
              }
              else {
                  password = null;
              }

              // Set Community User Avatar Picture to Public view access (default is Members)
              u.UserPreferencesShowProfilePicToGuestUsers = true;

              // Look for Person Account with the same Email Address
              List < Account > accList = [Select Id, FirstName, LastName, Country__c, Language__pc, PersonContactId From Account Where PersonEmail = : u.email Limit 1];
              if (accList.size() > 0) {
                  existedAccount = accList.get(0);
                  accountId = existedAccount.id;               
              }

              // Update Account's name if Person Account already exist and User is being created by the customer
              if (existedAccount != null && existedAccount.FirstName != null && existedAccount.LastName != null && (existedAccount.FirstName.trim() != u.FirstName.trim() || existedAccount.LastName.trim() != u.LastName.trim())) {

                  Contact conToUpdate = new Contact(Id = existedAccount.PersonContactId);
                  conToUpdate.FirstName = u.FirstName;
                  conToUpdate.LastName = u.LastName;
                  update conToUpdate;
                  System.debug('conToUpdate'+conToUpdate);
              }   

              // Hardcode English US for renault & nissan;
              u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';

              System.debug('#@####' + u + ' ' + accountId + '!' );
              // lastName is a required field on user, but if it isn't specified, we'll default it to the username
              String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);    
              System.debug('userId' + userId);
              // Hardcode English US for renault & nissan;
              User user = [SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id = : userId];
              if (user != null) {
                  Contact contact = [SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = : user.ContactId LIMIT 1];                
                  Account account = [SELECT Country__c, Language__pc FROM Account WHERE Id = : contact.AccountId LIMIT 1];

                  if (account != null) {   
                      List < Country__c > countryList = [SELECT Id FROM Country__c WHERE ISO_Code__c = 'US' LIMIT 1];
                      account.Country__c = countryList.get(0).id;
                      account.Language__pc = 'English (US)';
                      update account;
                      System.debug('account' +account);
                  }
              }
              // END: Hardcode of English US

              if (userId != null) { 
                  if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                      ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(email, password, startUrl);
                      aura.redirect(lgn);

                  }
                  else {
                      ApexPages.PageReference confirmRef = new PageReference(regConfirmUrl);
                      aura.redirect(confirmRef);
                  }
              }
              return null;
          }
          catch (Exception ex) {
              Database.rollback(sp);
              SystemLoggerUtil.logError(ex);
              return ex.getMessage();            
          }
     }    

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Map<String,Object>> getExtraFields(String extraFieldsFieldSet) { 
        List<Map<String,Object>> extraFields = new List<Map<String,Object>>();
        Schema.FieldSet fieldSet = Schema.SObjectType.User.fieldSets.getMap().get(extraFieldsFieldSet);
        if (fieldSet != null) {
            for (Schema.FieldSetMember f : fieldSet.getFields()) {
                Map<String, Object> fieldDetail = new Map<String, Object>();
                fieldDetail.put('dbRequired', f.getDBRequired());
                fieldDetail.put('fieldPath', f.getFieldPath());
                fieldDetail.put('label', f.getLabel());
                fieldDetail.put('required', f.getRequired());
                fieldDetail.put('type', f.getType());
                fieldDetail.put('value', '');   // client will populate
                extraFields.add(fieldDetail);
            }
        }
        return extraFields;
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the Portal USER, but the user who CREATES the Portal user.

As test code should be run as specific users (using `System.RunAs()`), you should create a new user in your test code, assign that user a Role, and then run the `createPortalUser` method as that user. This will avoid your errors.

And yes, you should also give yourself a role as well. In fact, go ahead and give every internal user a role, just to be complete and to allow control of record visibility using the role hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The Guest user assigned to new accounts created by community self-registration has no role. I solved this problem by adding logic to the `Insert Before` trigger on the `Account` object that reassigns accounts owned by this user to a "real" user. You may want to come up with a more elegant method that doesn't embed record Id's, but this should work.

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account ( before insert ) {
    if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) 
        AccountTriggerHandler.beforeInsert(Trigger.New);
}

public without sharing class AccountTriggerHandler {

    public static void beforeInsert (List<Account> accounts) {
        system.debug('AccountTriggerHandler.beforeInsert accounts: ' + accounts);
        Id guestId = '0056A00000zzzzzzzz'; // the Id of the Guest User in the community
        Id defaultOwnerId = '0056A00000zzzzzzzz'; // the Id of a "real" user
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (account.OwnerId == guestId ) {
                account.OwnerId = defaultOwnerId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your username has a role assigned to it.  Salesforce will not allow a portal contact to be created if the owner/creator doesn't have a role.

You might also check that the portal account's owner has a role assigned to it.  See this post for the reason:  [Any documentation on the CreatePortalUser?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45702/any-documentation-on-the-createportaluser/45721#45721)